# Powershell - question about for each / variables

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, foreach

I have this simple question about my code. I would like to create an array for pushing my variables into database mssql.

My first problem is about the definitions of variables. The PowerShell ISE response to me is this error code:
`You must provide a value expression following the '%' operator`. I would like to understand how to correctly define the variables $CPUPer.CPU % and Memory (MB). I suppose it's a simple use of quotes on those properties, but i don't know what to do.

Next goal is to collect this variable and push into database table. I hope the code is correct but I probably need any suggestions.

This is an extract of my output in the array $CPUPercent :

```
Name                                          CPU CPU %  Memory (MB) Description                                                     
----                                          --- -----  ----------- -----------                                                     
dwm                                       1225.47  5.37 240.91796875 Desktop Window Manager                                             
chrome                                     679.33  2.99  359.3828125 Google Chrome                                                      
chrome                                     497.44  2.19   251.390625 Google Chrome                                                      
chrome                                     393.58  2.15   415.515625 Google Chrome
```

---

```
$CPUPercent = @{Name='CPU %';Expression={$TotalSec=(New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds;[Math]::Round( ($_.CPU * 100 / $TotalSec), 2)}};$CPU = @{Name='CPU';Expression={[Math]::Round($_.cpu,2)}}; Get-Process | Select -Property Name, $CPU, $CPUPercent,@{Name='Memory (MB)';Expression={($_.WorkingSet64/1MB)}}, Description | Sort -Property CPU -Descending | Format-Table -AutoSize
$CPUPercent = Get-Process | Select -Property Name, $CPU, $CPUPercent,@{Name='Memory (MB)';Expression={($_.WorkingSet64/1MB)}}, Description | Sort -Property CPU -Descending | Format-Table -AutoSize


foreach($CPUPer in $CPUPercent)
{
$name_1=$CPUPer.Name
$cpu_1=$CPUPer.CPU
$cpu_percent_1=$CPUPer.CPU %
$memory_1=$CPUPer.Memory (MB)
$descr_1=$CPUPer.Description

#$insertquery="
#INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceTable]
#           ([Name]
#           ,[CPU]
#           ,[CPU_Perc]
#           ,[Memory_MB]
#           ,[Description])
#     VALUES
#           ('$name_1'
#           ,'$cpu_1'
#           ,'$cpu_percent_1'
#           ,'$memory_1'
#           ,'$descr_1')
#GO
#"
#Invoke-SQLcmd -ServerInstance 'KILIKOOD-PC\MSSQLSERVER,1433' -query $insertquery -U sa -P test123 -Database Fantasy
}
```

Comment: `$CPUPer.CPU %` -> `$CPUPer.'CPU %'`; `$CPUPer.Memory (MB)` -> `$CPUPer.'Memory (MB)'` - property names that contain spaces and unusual characters require quoting.

Answer (score 0):

I think use ' ' for names will solve your problem, check it out
$CPUPer.'CPU %'
$CPUPer.'Memory (MB)'